# Show that if $r$ is nilpotent in a ring with identity, then $1-r$ is a unit in $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring. An element $r \in R$ is called nilpotent if $r^n=0$ for some integer $n \ge 1$. Show that if $r$ is nilpotent in a ring with identity, then $1-r$ is a unit in $R$.

Proof. Recall that in any ring we have $(−a)(−b) = (ab)$ Thus in
any ring with 1 (commutative or not) we have the following identities:

$1 −(−1)^na^n = (1 + a)(1 − a + a^2 − · · · + (−1)^{−1}a^{n−1})$

If $a^n = 0$ then we obtain an inverse $1 − a$

Now, I'm not so familiar with series and am not sure if this suffices. I also assume this can be shown with matrices, integers....as long as it is a ring

Comment: This is the third question you've asked recently closed because it duplicates many previous questions. Please take advantage of the search feature before you ask a question.

Comment: @rschwieb, I find that the search is very  specific and that you have to be very general to get decent results. But then there are too many questions to sift through. I have not found a good way to filter down the results, but thanks. I have gotten away from searching recently because of that. I will make a better effort to do so

Answer (score 8):

$$1=1-r^n=(1-r)(1+r+\ldots+r^{n-1})$$